# Margin auto not working in simple html/css code

Tags: css, html

As demonstrated here - http://jsfiddle.net/d4wUu/, I could not get the red bordered box with the word "Testing" to center along the height of the black box containing it. It stays aligned to the top border of the black box, leaving some space below it.

`margin-top` is not working either. Any idea how I can get `margin: auto` or `margin-top` (with respect to the black box containing it) to work on the red bordered box here?

Comment: It appears as though you're using divs when there are more semantically appropriate tags available:  `header` (`#heading`), `h1` (`#heading-title`), and `p` (`#main-text`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to vertically center the element. As far as I know, `margin: auto` will not work vertically on the element unless you use some type of table/table-cell styling.

These additions to your CSS is one way to vertically center it:

```
#heading {  
    position:relative;
}
#heading-title {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px; /* this is half the height of the element */
}
```

Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4wUu/2/) show this working.

Comment: I think I will go with the table method. Thanks for the input! +1

Comment: display: table-cell broke everything. e.g. width 100% will not work. so i am going with this instead.

Comment: Addition: instead of using top 50% (which strangely disabled margin-top on my website), i was able to use just margin-top. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4wUu/3/)

add those:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

to `#heading`.

Comment: I suppose this is the cleanest way to do it. Thanks! +1 and accept.

Comment: Correction: I noticed that width: 100% no longer work for the black box. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Could you show it "not working"?  Because it looks like it works in the fiddle to me.

Answer (score -1):

Another workaround,

Give `margin: 7px auto` to `#heading-title`.

Here `7px` because the height of the parent element is 65px and height of the child element is 50px. There difference in height is `15px`. so, dividing the `15px` between the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`.

This technique can only be used if the height of the parent and child elements are **fixed** as it is in the OP's description above.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4wUu/5/)**

Comment: Sorry, this isn't it. All I wanted is to vertically center the red bordered box, without altering the height of the black box or the vertical position.

Comment: P.S. I did not -1 you. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: @Legendre I don't mind if someone downvotes me. Those are just points to me. Anyway, I updated my post which is not a good solution but if the heights of the elements are fixed then you can try my solution.

Comment: Unless you have absolute control over the element's size (eg. an image), you can't reliably use top/bottom margins for vertical alignment.

Comment: @cimmanon Here the height of the parent and child elements are fixed.

Comment: Are they really?  http://jsfiddle.net/d4wUu/6/.  You can't pretend to control text *ever*.

Comment: @cimmanon Well, check the other posts on this page too. http://jsfiddle.net/d4wUu/7/ http://jsfiddle.net/d4wUu/8/. You don't have a reason here to downvote me.

Comment: It wasn't 100% clear auto-centering was called for. I think the downvotes are kinda lame. Not to mention, nobody's nuking the answer which also posts a height-reliant answer.